# Is the Stack Overflow OpenID component open source?

Tags: feature-request, openid, open-source

I love the whole OpenID/Google/Yahoo/AOL login system of Stack Overflow.

Are there any plans to open this component, and the backing code for authentication, up to the public? You talked about carving out the useful components of SO, like OpenID and markdown++, for open source distribution on the podcast.

Your OpenID implementation is quite slick and I could see it benefiting the community.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, already done:

http://dotnetopenauth.net/